# F# script change argument in function

Tags: f#-interactive

I've just studied F# scripting, and I have a strange situation with changing variable in it:

```
let ParseActual (arg:string) = let mutable value = false
                               if arg.[1] = '-' then value <- false
                               else value <- true
                               if arg.[1] = '-' || arg.[1] = '+' then ref arg := arg.Remove(0,2)
                               else (
                                        Console.WriteLine(arg)
                                        ref arg := arg.Remove(0,1)
                                        Console.WriteLine(arg)
                                    )
                               AddActual(arg, value)
```

But it doesn't change the string. First output `\r` and second is the same `\r`. What's wrong removing some characters from string and assigning it a new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arg` string is immutable. What you can do is to use the string to create and return a new string with changed literal but you won't be able to mutate the existing string. 
It's the case with all variables (not the most fortunate word, I know) in F#, once they are created and bound to a value they cannot be changed (unless you explicitly use the `mutable` keyword, as you did for the bool `value`).

Comment: yeah I know the keyword mutable, i've used it already. If I write `let mutable arg1 = arg` and change arg1 will it work? Or I should create a new string and assign it to mutable variable

Comment: I would go for creating a new string entirely. It's more idiomatic for F# and for functional programming.